# Propagate a reject if a promise returns an error, from inside it's .fail()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have the following piece of code:

```
var myFunc = function(id, obj, backupObj) {
  return update(obj) // this returns a promise
  .fail(function(err){
    // if update is rejected
    restore(id, backupObj); // i wish to run this
    // and return the error that 'update(obj)' threw and propagate it
    return Q.reject(err); // should it be thrown like this???
  });
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle the failure of `update()` and return the error, so when `myFunc()` is called from any place it can be propagated and finally handled? For example, being executed inside a chain:

```
var foo = function(id, obj) {
  var backupObj = {};

  return checkIfValidObj(obj)
  .then(function(_backupObj) {
    backupObj = _backupObj;
    return doSomethingElse(id, obj);
  })
  .then(function() {
    // here!
    return myFunc(id, obj, backupObj);
  });
}
```

And then, as the `foo` caller, I would like to do some error handling and be able to catch the error that `update(obj).fail()` might return:

```
foo()
.then(function() { /* everything worked as expected, so we are happy */ })
.catch(function(err){ 
   // I want this to be executed also if 'update(obj)' inside 'myFunc' was rejected!
});
```

Comment: Yes, both `throw err;` as well as `return Q.reject(err);` (they're equivalent) are the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @Bergi's link answers the question for Q, not just Dojo, because this is covered by [The Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-42), so will be true of any A+-style promise lib.